# How can I rename a layer group or a layer with the same name using an action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I have quite a bit projects which contain a **layer group** by the name "Cover" and I want to rename it to "Cover Group" using this action.

[image]

But into "Cover" **layer group** there is a **layer** with the **same name**. So when my **action** starts, **instead** of find and **rename** the **layer group** "Cover", **renames** the **layer** "Cover"!!!

[image]

[image]

Any idea how can I define my action so to rename the layer group and not the layer?

Comment: I can't understand you. Have you solved your problems ?Theoretically, you can rename the layer or layer group by double click in photoshop.

Comment: I have close to 1000 projects which contain a group by the name "Cover" and a layer with the same name. I made an action so to rename group to "Cover Group". But everytime I run it, instead of rename group "Cover" to "Cover Group", renames the layer "Cover" to "Cover Group". What I am looking for is how to make action "understand" that I want to rename the group and not the layer.

Comment: Does it work if there is no clash of names?  If so, do it in 3 steps: rename the layer to something temporary, then rename the layer group (no clash now), then rename the layer back to its original name.

Comment: Yes, this is how I am doing it after all!!! :)